# Building QGIS for Windows with mingw and Cmake?

Tags: windows, mingw, cmake, qgis

Does anyone knows how to build QGIS for Windows with mingw and Cmake? Having that I have all required dependencies installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really nice workaround at:

http://www.webalice.it/marco.pasetti/qgis+grass/BuildFromSource.html